# How to make irregular designs responsive in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a home screen design where icons are vertically tilted (not a property stacked design). Also these navigational icons are connected by thick black connecting lines. I tried to use absolute positions but on different resolutions either icons are misaligned or those images are not reaching full screen edges. Can you please suggest how can we create such designs perfectly fit in all kind of resolutions?

[image]

Comment: Check react native's Dimensions API to get the width and height of the device the app is running on, and you can also percentage values like width: '20%'

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna have a really fun time to do this in RN but it is possible. You can use the transform property in the style to apply a rotation.

Check here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms#transform

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created the design using transform property and absolute positions but they getting out of alignment on different phones. Will SVG help?

Comment: Great. In that case please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting the screen size and positioning the each element using position absolute but it was still getting distorted in different mobiles.
If anyone still looking for an answer, I solved this using svg. (not sure if it is the best solution).
If you are not using expo then you need to use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg). It is already included in expo. Then you can create complex design as svg using sketch/adobe illustrator. Now edit svg image using any text editor and copy the code. "react-native-svg" supports most of the standard svg tags but there is slight difference (you can get that from documentation).

```
 <Svg height={height} width={width} viewBox="150 90 650 806">
     <G id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <G id="Group" transform="translate(1.000000, 0.000000)">
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(400.223611, 262.930718) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-400.223611, -262.930718) " x="440.723611" y="300.930718" width="41" height="46"></Rect>
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(481.794679, 552.516504) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-481.794679, -552.516504) " x="461.794679" y="525.516504" width="40" height="54"></Rect>
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(486.235804, 697.148232) rotate(45.000000) translate(-486.235804, -697.148232) " x="464.735804" y="671.648232" width="43" height="51"></Rect>
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(488.244426, 399.637825) rotate(45.000000) translate(-488.244426, -399.637825) " x="466.744426" y="366.637825" width="43" height="66"></Rect>
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(363.430718, 723.930718) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-363.430718, -723.930718) " x="343.430718" y="704.930718" width="40" height="38"></Rect>
            <Rect id="Rectangle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="translate(498.284271, 856.748737) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-498.284271, -856.748737) " x="475.784271" y="835.248737" width="45" height="43"></Rect>
</G></G></Svg>
```

This was some sample code for creating those connecting lines in the image. In svg you can easily create tilted graphics and fix their positions. It will automatically become responsive as per screen resolution.